# Divide NSInteger with int

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am trying to divide NSInteger with some number, but I am receiving errors.

This is what I am trying to do:

```
length = [corner count];
for (int i=0; i<length; i++) {
    if ([resultDate rangeOfString:[corner objectAtIndex:i]].location != NSNotFound) {
        cornerResult++;
    }
}

cornerResultLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", cornerResult];
```

This works as it should.. I search through the array and count the results and write it.

But, I need cornerResult divided with 4. When I add cornerResult / 4 it shows me the error(as I wrote in comment). I have no idea why is this making problem.

Comment: You shouldn't be getting errors, maybe you have a warning ?

Comment: invalid operand to the binary expression. 'NSInteger *' (aka int*) and int

Comment: I received that error, while compiling.

Comment: @boban0987: Is this code inside a function?

Comment: Please quote the precise error message, and show us a few lines either side of the above lines.  You're not making any sense.

Comment: the error probably indicated that the function which uses this division isn't declared in the .h files. (wild guess from googling around)

Comment: (Does the statement just ahead of your first statement above end with a semicolon?)

Comment: ok, sorry guys, I just added piece of code to explain

Comment: You still need to show the *actual* code you're compiling. Where is the first block within the second?

Comment: I edited question. First part of the code was just for testing purposes. Now I deleted it. Only what you see now is my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you probably meant to divide the `intValue` of the `NSNumber`, not the `NSNumber*` itself:

```
int num = number.intValue;
int result = num / 4;
```

(full code sample and error message would help)

Answer (score 2):

You are dividing an int which becomes a float , use %f instead.

Answer (score 0):

I fix it this way. First I defined int and after that I set NSInteger value to int and after that divide.

```
int helper = cornerResult;
helper = helper / 4;
```